# What beracha acharona when ikar less than kezayit?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements, eating

If you have an ikar (main) and tofel (secondary) mixture where the ikar is less than a kizayit but the entire mixture is greater than a kizayit, do you still make a beracha acharona on the ikar?

Or if you eat bread but not enough to bench (say birkat hamazon), but you eat other boreh-nefashot stuff that would require a boreh nefashot, do you say boreh nefashot or nothing at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If one eats two items each less than a *kezayis*, but together are a *kezayis* or more, the bracha acharona is *Borei Nefashos*.**

Thus, in both the case

1. *Ikar* is less than *kezayis*, but together with *tafel* is *kezayis*
2. Bread is less than *kezayis* but together with other food items is *kezayis*

you make a *borei nefashos* since although the flour component is less than the shiur kezayis, together, with the non flour component, there is a kezayis in total.

These cases are spelled out in *Mishne Berurah* 208:48 and 210:1, respectively.

Comment: But in the first case the tofel is neither a kezayit...

Comment: But together with the ikar you have a kezayis